# How to get 8 byte pointer value on 64 bit machine on gdb?

Tags: gdb

I am looking into a core from 64 bit system. Architecture is set correctly but still pointer value is printed as 4 bytes. What changes are needed to make it print 64 bit value ?

```
(gdb) p sizeof(void *)
$16 = 8

(gdb) p this
$15 = 0x4852200

(gdb) show architecture
The target architecture is assumed to be i386:x86-64:intel
```

Comment: Already answered, but if you want to see the whole thing, try p/z this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What changes are needed to make it print 64 bit value

GDB is *already* printing 64-bit value. It just so happens that the upper bits are 0.